# Is there a way to have choice options displayed as buttons in web channel bot via Prompts options to have multi select in V4 SDK using C#?

Tags: c#, botframework, bots, chatbot

Is there a way we can have the choice options displayed as buttons in web channel bot via Prompts options or via Cards to have multi select in V4 SDK using C#?

Let me explain my query through an example:
lets say i have series of options displayed and i want to perform an operation now i want these options to be displayed on a card with multi select enables for example like check box or selecting multiple buttons at a time such that the particular operation can be triggered for set of options selected.

Example:
Card 1:
Check box 1/button 1
Check box 2/button 2
Check box 3/button 3
.....so on so forth as the selection is dynamic in nature as list changes based o search criteria

lastly a button to start a process

Now if  i select 1 and 2 check boxes or buttons and click on start a process button the respective option should be triggered based on selected values.

Like wise if i have a an option of none it should un-select all and go back to the main window in this way multiple options to be displayed and performed.

Is this possible to achieve or the expectation is not valid?

If possible, please provide me a step by step detailed guide to achieve it as i am new to code and bot?

Language: C#
SDK: V4
Channel: Web chat channel

Thanks in Advance
-ChaitanyaNG

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/authoring-cards/card-schema#inputchoiceset
I hope this documentation will help you. 
Basically you need to set IsMultiselect = true